# How to Build and Test PJSIP 2.5.5 for IOS with IPv6 Support

Tags: ios, voip, ipv6, pjsip

I am using pjsip 2.5.5 for my project.
enabled IPv6 support by adding 
**#define PJ_HAS_IPV6 1**
in pj/config_site.h.
following (https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPv6).

With this I made build for linux and mac. build succeed and I tested by calling PIN to PIN (using --ipv6). It is working fine for IPv6 Addresses.

Now I made build for IOS and testing it in simulator using cli(telnet).
while checking account list using show (l) [for complete list of commands refer: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/PJSUA-CLI?format=pdf ] . It is showing only IPv4 accounts (UDP and TCP), NO IPv6 Accounts.

Where I am going wrong?

Is there any flag need to define?

How to test pjsip build with ipv6 for IOS using pjsua?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to include your code in the question, not as a link to an external site as they can disappear.  Please read [ask] and see if you can provide an [mcve]

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Have you tried same built on physical device, not a simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create both the transport at the same time like below.

```
/* Add UDP transport. */
status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &app_config->udp_cfg, 
&transport_id);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
    goto error;
}

/* Add UDP6 transport. */
status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP6, &app_config->udp_cfg, 
&transport_id);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
    goto error;
}
```

For TCP and TLS you also need to do same as above.

**Happy to help all :)**